# How to automate JavaScript files compression with YUI Compressor?

Tags: javascript, batch-file, yui

[YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) does not accept wildcard parameters, so I cannot run it like this:

```
C:>java -jar yuicompressor.jar *.js
```

But I have over 500 files and would rather not have to create a batch file like this:

```
C:>java -jar yuicompressor.jar file1.js -o deploy\file1.js
C:>java -jar yuicompressor.jar file2.js -o deploy\file2.js
...
C:>java -jar yuicompressor.jar file500.js -o deploy\file500.js
```

And of course my file names are *not* in such uniform way.

Is there way to automate this without writing any code? :)

Comment: YUICompressor supports wildcards starting from version 2.4.4. See below for download links.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I might go for a makefile (I think it would probably be more maintainable long term), but if you want a quick-n-dirty Windows batch command something like the following should work:

```
for %%a in (*.js) do @java -jar yuicompressor.jar "%%a" -o "deploy\%%a"
```

Comment: It works good if there are no spaces in the file name. Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to throw quotes in there - I'll edit that in.

Comment: Yep, that did it!  
The last thing I need to overcome is to be able to run this batch file from folder A, have all .js files in folder B, and put output files into folder C.

Comment: I feared that this might wander down the "Advanced Batch Scripting Hell Hole"...  You can have positional parameters to batch files using %1 %2 %3, etc. However, this is when you start running into **HUGE** problems with trying to combine and quote entities that might have spaces.  Insanity follows.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I can always run my batch from the folder where all the .js files are. So, it's not critical.

Comment: Running this twice would cause all files that are already minified be minified again, with filenames resulting in .min.min.min.js and so on. Can you maybe avoid that by only minifying files that are not already minified?

Answer (score 5):

If you are geared towards Java, you can also use Ant for conversion. I've found a [blog entry](http://blog.gomilko.com/2007/11/29/yui-compression-tool-as-ant-task/) about an [Ant Taks for the YUI Compressor](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/ubikwiki/index.php?title=Minifying_JS/CSS). Disclaimer: Never tried it - sorry

Comment: Another ant task can be found at https://bitbucket.org/m6_russell_francis/yui-compressor-ant-task I use it in several projects to automate the compression of js/css files. As the author I may be slightly biased.

Answer (score 5):

YUI compressor now supports wildcards, starting from version 2.4.4. You can get the latest version [here](http://yuilibrary.com/download/yuicompressor/) or from [YUI Git Hub](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor).

Answer (score 4):

I should mention that using GNU Make, I have the following rule:

```
%-min.js: %.js
    ${java} -jar ${compressor} $< -o ${<:.js=-min.js}
```

Comment: Why are you using `${<:.js=-min.js}` instead of just `$@`?

Comment: Because there is a LOT about GNU Make I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

And for unix or cygwin you can use xargs or something like:

ls -1 *.js | awk '{printf("java -jar yuicompressor.jar %s -o deploy/%s",$1,$1)}'

Pipe that to /bin/sh when you're happy with the command line to execute it.

Comment: and for a recursive version use find instead of ls

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use some sort of a script to get a list of all the .js files, and then runs the YUI Compressor on all of them.  On the windows command prompt, something like this should work:

```
FOR %f IN (*.js) DO java -jar yuicompressor.jar %f -o deploy\%f
```