# YUI Compressor - Automate Javascript Compression but skip some files

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, minify, windows-shell, yui-compressor

I am following the suggested answer on this SO post:

[How to automate JavaScript files compression with YUI Compressor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227288/how-to-automate-javascript-files-compression-with-yui-compressor)

However, in my ~/Scripts folder, I have several jQuery files that are already compressed and minified. What do I need to do to automate it in a similar fashion but skip the jQuery files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could name all of your uncompressed files `whatever.max.js`, and then change the rule to something like this:

```
for %%a in (*.max.js) do @java -jar yuicompressor.jar "%%a" -o "deploy\%%a"
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
cd ~/Scripts
find . -name "*jquery*" -prune -o -type d -o -exec java -jar yuicompressor.jar -o '.js$:-min.js' {} +
```