# Using YUI compressor with Netbeans

Tags: javascript, css, netbeans, minify

Is it possible to use [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) automaticly, and deploy to a FTP server, using Netbeans for php ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use ANT in Netbeans, just like it can be done in Eclipse.  [Automate Eclipse "Yui Compressor..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279023/automate-eclipse-yui-compressor/9280382#9280382)

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with a PHP project for example, you could have a script execute when you hit F6 (Run) that does this work for you. Its setup in the project properties configuration.

See this link:
http://webartisan.se/yui-compressor-netbeans/