# ant + yuicompressor path error

Tags: java, ant, yui-compressor

I've got a file in *C:\Bin\test.js* that I would like to compress and have renamed *test-min.js*

my ant **build.xml** looks like this:

```
<property name="temp.dir" value="C:\Bin\"/>

<apply executable="java" parallel="false" dest="${temp.dir}">
   <fileset dir="${temp.dir}" includes="test.js"/>
   <arg line="-jar"/>
   <arg path="${yui.dir}"/>
   <srcfile/>
   <arg line="-o"/>
   <mapper type="glob" from="*.js" to="*-min.js"/>
   <targetfile/>
</apply>
```

I get the following Java error:

[apply] **java.io.FileNotFoundException: Bintest-min.js:\Bin\test.js** (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

I've tried every combination of pathing and filenames I could come up with. What am I missing? It looks like it's stripping out C:\ and the second \

And I know YUI works because I can do it manually from the command line.

Comment: Go straight to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19339287/672455 The accepted answer does no good

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ran into this problem after upgrading to yuicompressor 2.4.8

There is a knows bug in 2.4.8 where it does not handle the quoted paths generated by ant.

Going back to 2.4.7 fixed the issue for me.  You can download 2.4.7 here:
https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/downloads

You can find discussion of the issue here:
http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2013/05/16/yuicompressor-2-4-8-released/

"New version 2.4.8 fails to parse Windows filename in quotes correctly. 2.4.7 works fine. Eg, command java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar “d:\work\common_source.js” –charset utf-8 –disableoptimizations -v -o “d:\work\common.js” gives error java.io.FileNotFoundException: workcommon.js:\work\coomon_source.js (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect). Unfortunately, this renders it entirely unusable."

And the YUI Compressor defect is here:
https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/78

Comment: this is is the real answer guys, if you struggle the way I did, you will thank this guy a lot!

Comment: I switched this to the accepted answer even though in the other answer I had posted this same info. I'm doing this for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into these sort of problems in the past, try /Bin

Comment: No good. I tried that. It's 'escaping' the destination path... so instead of being c:\Bin\test-min.js it says Bintest-min.js

Comment: I lied. Thanks @EGHM - that solved it. I had to set both the target and destination path to /Bin and it work. (I could have sweared I tried that already.)

Comment: After some more tests - It's actually something to do with yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar as soon as I went back to yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar it worked. Hope that helps someone out there in the ether.

Comment: Good idea trying a previous version.  Another thing to to try in these cases is escaping the \ by using \\

Comment: @Chris check the second comment from the top - it appears to have worked for Chenzo.

Comment: @Schorsch I saw that, but then in the third comment he resorted to downgrading yuicompressor, so after more testing Chenze presumably found that it didn't work after all.