# how to minify JavaScript files using Eclipse JSDT?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsdt

How to "build" `*.min.js` and `*.min.js.map` files using Eclipse JSDT (JavaScript Developement Tools)?

Comment: http://jscompress.com/

Comment: can't I do it with Eclipse?

Comment: https://github.com/oncereply/jscompressor

Comment: jscompressor doesn't generate map files ;/ It is also not very comfortable tool

Answer (score 2):

You can use an external builder to run build scripts for your Javascript tasks.

Go to **Project --> Properties** and choose Builders.  Then you can add an external builder to launch an external program with whatever arguments you need.

[image: Setting up an external builder for NPM]

You can se the builder to run automatically by using the Build Options tab and setting the "Run The Builder:" options:

[image]

Comment: how to add the "browserify" builder on Windows?

Comment: The process is the same. However instead of have a path like /usr/bin/npm though you would just use a path like C:\tools\sometool.exe ... the 'browserify' part is not really relevant to the process BTW, you can set up any external command you want for the builder.

Comment: What builder can I use on Windows?

Comment: You can set up a builder for whatever external you would normally use for processing your JS files... if you have something like a grunt file you could just call that, or you could use some external tool directly like http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/

Comment: sorry I am new to JavaScript ;/ How to use this lisperator.net/uglifyjs ?

Answer (score 1):

I use [YUICompressor](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/yuicompressor). It works on both JavaScript and CSS. Once it's installed, it's easy to use:

1. Right-click the JS file you'd like to minimize
2. Go to External Tools > Compress Javascript
3. Specify the name of the compressed file and click Finish

Unfortunately, you will need to manually run the compressor every time you change the original file, which can get tedious if you're working with lots of files. If you want to automate the process, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279023/automate-eclipse-yui-compressor). I ended up writing a quick batch script for my project.

Comment: Give me an error "The chosen operation is not currently available"